# compile stylesheet error while transforming XML

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I'm trying to transform my XML using XSLT.

Below is my code, XML and XSLT

Parameters:

```
stylesheetPathname: /home/Jon/XSLT.xsl
inputPathname:/home/Jon/countries.xml
outputPathname:/home/Jon/cTransformedXML.xml
```

Code:

```
public static void xmlProcessor(String stylesheetPathname, String inputPathname, String outputPathname ) throws TransformerException {

    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Source stylesheetSource = new StreamSource(new File(stylesheetPathname));
    Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(stylesheetSource);
    Source inputSource = new StreamSource(new File(inputPathname));
    Result outputResult = new StreamResult(new File(outputPathname));
    transformer.transform(inputSource, outputResult);

}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- <!DOCTYPE countries SYSTEM "countries.dtd"> -->
<!-- xmlns="http://www.example.org/countries" -->
<countries>
  <!-- xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="countries.xsd" -->
  <country name="Afghanistan" population="22664136" area="647500">
    <language percentage="11">Turkic</language>
    <language percentage="35">Pashtu</language>
    <language percentage="50">Afghan Persian</language>
  </country>
  <country name="Albania" population="3249136" area="28750" />
  <country name="Algeria" population="29183032" area="2381740">
    <city>
      <name>Algiers</name>
      <population>1507241</population>
    </city>
  </country>
  <country name="American Samoa" population="59566" area="199" />
  <country name="Andorra" population="72766" area="450" />
  <country name="Angola" population="10342899" area="1246700" />
  <country name="Anguilla" population="10424" area="91">
    <language percentage="100">English</language>
  </country>
  <country name="Antigua and Barbuda" population="65647" area="440">
    <language percentage="100">English</language>
  </country>
  <country name="Argentina" population="34672996" area="2766890">
    <city>
      <name>La Matanza</name>
      <population>1111811</population>
    </city>
    <city>
      <name>Cordoba</name>
      <population>1208713</population>
    </city>
    <city>
      <name>Rosario</name>
      <population>1118984</population>
    </city>
    <city>
      <name>Buenos Aires</name>
      <population>2988006</population>
    </city>
  </country>
  <country name="Armenia" population="3463574" area="29800">
    <city>
      <name>Yerevan</name>
      <population>1200000</population>
    </city>
    <language percentage="2">Russian</language>
    <language percentage="96">Armenian</language>
  </country>
  <country name="Aruba" population="67794" area="193" />
  <country name="Australia" population="18260864" area="7686850">
    <city>
      <name>Sydney</name>
      <population>3657000</population>
    </city>
    <city>
      <name>Brisbane</name>
      <population>1302000</population>
    </city>
    <city>
      <name>Adelaide</name>
      <population>1050000</population>
    </city>
    <city>
      <name>Melbourne</name>
      <population>3081000</population>
    </city>
    <city>
      <name>Perth</name>
      <population>1193000</population>
    </city>
    <language percentage="100">English</language>
  </country>
  <country name="Austria" population="8023244" area="83850">
    <city>
      <name>Vienna</name>
      <population>1583000</population>
    </city>
    <language percentage="100">German</language>
  </country>
  <country name="Azerbaijan" population="7676953" area="86600">
    <city>
      <name>Baku</name>
      <population>1740000</population>
    </city>
    <language percentage="3">Russian</language>
    <language percentage="2">Armenian</language>
    <language percentage="89">Azeri</language>
  </country>
  <country name="Bahamas" population="259367" area="13940" />
  <country name="Bahrain" population="590042" area="620" />
  <country name="Bangladesh" population="123062800" area="144000">
    <city>
      <name>Dhaka</name>
      <population>3839000</population>
    </city>
    <city>
      <name>Chittagong</name>
      <population>1599000</population>
    </city>
  </country>
</countries>
```

XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <countries>
         <xsl:for-each select="//country">
            <xsl:sort select="@population" order="descending" data-type="number" />
            <country>
               <name>
                  <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
               </name>
               <population>
                  <xsl:value-of select="@population" />
               </population>
               <area>
                  <xsl:value-of select="@area" />
               </area>
               <cities>
                  <xsl:for-each select="city">
                     <xsl:sort select="population" order="descending" />
                     <city>
                        <name>
                           <xsl:value-of select="name" />
                        </name>
                        <population>
                           <xsl:value-of select="population" />
                        </population>
                     </city>
                  </xsl:for-each>
               </cities>
            </country>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </countries>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Below is the error am getting while running the above mentioned in eclipse.

```
"ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'
FATAL ERROR:  '/home/Jon/eclipse-workspace/spark-app/"/home/Jon/XSLT.xsl" (No such file or directory)'
           :/home/Jon/eclipse-workspace/spark-app/"/home/Jon/XSLT.xsl" (No such file or directory)
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: /home/Jon/eclipse-workspace/spark-app/"/home/Jon/XSLT.xsl" (No such file or directory)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:988)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:761)
    at sparkProject.XMLTransformer.xmlProcessor(XMLTransformer.java:19)
    at sparkProject.StartingPoint.main(StartingPoint.java:21)
```

I'm kind of stuck in this, not able to figure out, what's the problem ..?

I'm doing something wrong with my XSL or any code issue ..?

Please suggest ..!

Answer (score 1):

It's reporting an error in a bizarre filename

```
'/home/Jon/eclipse-workspace/spark-app/"/home/Jon/XSLT.xsl"
```

and that suggests to me strongly that the paths supplied to your `xmlProcessor` method are not what you think they are; either that, or they are being resolved against some strange base directory.

Comment: Can you please tell, what can be tried..? Not sure why its coming. Becasue after priting the paths in method, all seems to be correct.

Comment: My guess would be that the value of `stylesheetPathName` contains a leading double-quotes character.